# Cannot get rid of backslash with jQuery's replace function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having issues getting rid of the backlash symbol. I'm trying to convert a url like this: /apple to /fruit#apple

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.product').each(function () {

        var productLink = $(this).find('a').attr('href');

        productLink.replace(/\//, "");

        productLink = "/fruits#" + $(this);


    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
        <h2>Fruit 1</h2>
        <a href="/apple">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <h2>Fruit 2</h2>
        <a href="/orange">Learn More</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have to use `'/fruits' + productLink`

Comment: You also need to change the actual attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were just missing the "put the result as attribute" part:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.product').each(function () {

        var productLink = $(this).find('a').attr('href').replace(/\//, "");

        $(this).find('a').attr('href', "/fruits#" + productLink );


    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
        <h2>Fruit 1</h2>
        <a href="/apple">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <h2>Fruit 2</h2>
        <a href="/orange">Learn More</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for checking it out, but that still doesn't get rid of the backslash before apple or orange.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, fixed now